# serve -s build specify port number

Tags: reactjs, digital-ocean, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm trying to serve a react-app's build folder from a DigitalOcean droplet.

After I run `yarn build`, I get told by the script to run

`yarn global add serve
serve -s build`

However, when I run `serve -s build`, It say's it's running on http://localhost:5000. I would like it run on localhost:3000 instead, as I have another server running on port 5000. How can i specify the port number such that `serve -s build` runs on port 3000?

Comment: You can use the `-l` option (lowercase L). `serve -l 3000 -s build`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From typing `serve --help`, I found

```
-l, --listen listen_uri            
Specify a URI endpoint on which to listen

For TCP ports on hostname "localhost":

$ serve -l 1234
```

In your case, you can just use

```
serve -l 3000 -s build
```

to specify that you want to serve the app on port 3000